# How to make the automatic shift of fleqn work with alignat?

Tags: alignat

I use the `fleqn` option with the standard `mathindent` setting. That nicely shifts equations further to the left if they would collide with the right page margin.

With `alignat`, however, that does not work. As a workaround, I set the `mathindent` manually with `\setlength{\mathindent}{10pt}` for the equation, where I needed the space and reset it to what I found to be the default value `\setlength{\mathindent}{\dimen102}` after that equation. Now for all following equations, that automatic shifting does not work anymore.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newdimen{\oldmathindent}
\setlength{\oldmathindent}{\mathindent}

\begin{document}

Some short equation, which has the default \texttt{mathindent} due to \texttt{fleqn}:
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2.
\end{equation}
Some long equation, which automatically has a smaller \texttt{mathindent} due to its length and a collision with the right margin:
\begin{equation}
v = \left[ \begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]^\top.
\end{equation}
Now some long equation with \texttt{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{4}
\nonumber \ddot{x}_c &= -&&\frac{1}{m_c(\Delta m_c)} &&[&& F_s(x_c-x_w,u_1,\Delta m_c) + F_d(x_c-x_w,\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + F_f(\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + \\ &&&&&&&  +F_{fc}(\dot(x_c)) + F_{Delta m_c}( \Delta m_c ) ]   \\ 
\nonumber \ddot{x}_w &= -&&\frac{1}{m_w} &&[&& F_s(x_c-x_w,u_1) + F_d(x_c-x_w,\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + F_f(\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + \\ &&&&&&&  +F_{fc}(\dot(x_c))].
\end{alignat}
The same long equation with \emph{alignat} but manual set of \texttt{mathindent} to 0
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{alignat}{4}
\nonumber \ddot{x}_c &= -&&\frac{1}{m_c(\Delta m_c)} &&[&& F_s(x_c-x_w,u_1,\Delta m_c) + F_d(x_c-x_w,\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + F_f(\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + \\ &&&&&&&  +F_{fc}(\dot(x_c)) + F_{Delta m_c}( \Delta m_c ) ]   \\ 
\nonumber \ddot{x}_w &= -&&\frac{1}{m_w} &&[&& F_s(x_c-x_w,u_1) + F_d(x_c-x_w,\dot(x_c)-    \dot(x_w)) + F_f(\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + \\ &&&&&&&  +F_{fc}(\dot(x_c))].
\end{alignat}\\
\setlength{\mathindent}{\oldmathindent}
And now - after setting back the \texttt{mathindent} to \texttt{oldmathindent}, the same short equation from above looks like this:
\begin{equation}
v = \left[ \begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]^\top.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that the layout of the long `alignat` equation is how I want it. If anyone has an idea how to achieve that without `alignat`, that would be fine for me, too.

Thanks!

edit_0528: I applied the changes suggested by *barbara beeton* (if I got it right). However, all equations after the `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` start at the very left, disregarding the `\setlength{\mathindent}{\oldmathindent}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of saving and restore use:

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{alignat}{4}
\nonumber \ddot{x}_c &= -&&\frac{1}{m_c(\Delta m_c)} &&[&& F_s(x_c-x_w,u_1,\Delta m_c) + F_d(x_c-x_w,\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + F_f(\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + \\ &&&&&&&  +F_{fc}(\dot(x_c)) + F_{Delta m_c}( \Delta m_c ) ]   \\ 
\nonumber \ddot{x}_w &= -&&\frac{1}{m_w} &&[&& F_s(x_c-x_w,u_1) + F_d(x_c-x_w,\dot(x_c)-    \dot(x_w)) + F_f(\dot(x_c)-\dot(x_w)) + \\ &&&&&&&  +F_{fc}(\dot(x_c))].
\end{alignat}
\endgroup
```

Answer (score 2):

although you've chosen the appropriate `\dimen`, what the command
`\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` does is *reset* `\dimen102`.  so you no longer
have access to the original value.

save the original value of `\mathindent` thus in the preamble:

```
\newdimen{\oldmathindent}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\oldmathindent}{\mathindent}%
}
```

then, instead of  `\setlength{\mathindent}{\dimen102}`, specify

```
\setlength{\mathindent}{\oldmathindent}
```

**edit:** it turns out that `\mathindent` itself isn't set until after
`\begin{document}`, so trying to set `\oldmathindent` in the preamble has
no useful effect.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't quite work. I added `\newdimen{\oldmathindent}` and `\setlength{\oldmathindent}{\mathindent}` to my preamble, changed the mathindent for the long equation with `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` and afterwards modified the `\setlength{\mathindent}{\dimen102}` to `\setlength{\mathindent}{\oldmathindent}`. Did I get you wrong? The result is that all following equations have a mathident of 0pt.

Comment: @Bazi -- i finally had a chance to test this recommendation, and found why it wasn't working.  answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You make two errors:

1. You should use `\newlength{\oldmathindent}` and not `\newdimen`, because `\mathindent` is a rubber length.
2. You should save the value of `\mathindent` at begin document, not in the preamble, where its value is still –1sp (it's not zero, in order to use it as a signal).

So you should do

```
\newlength{\oldmathindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\oldmathindent}{\mathindent}}
```

The value set by `amsmath` at begin document is `29.3747pt minus 29.3747pt` and the `minus` part is essential.

```
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{%
    \@fleqntrue
    \@mathmargin = -1sp
    \let\mathindent=\@mathmargin
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \ifdim\@mathmargin= -1sp
            \@mathmargin\leftmargini minus\leftmargini
        \fi
    }%
}
```

As you see, `amsmath` uses `\@mathmargin`, but the `fleqn` option makes `\mathindent` equivalent to `\@mathmargin`, but the value is set later, when the value of `\leftmargini` is known.

Of course, resetting `\mathindent` in a group is the best path.